# Ensuring background thread execution is ran given enough time to finish when running unit test in .Net

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, dispose

My NUnit test creates an instance of a class under test. A constructor of that class spans two background (with old style `Thread t = new Thread(myvoidreturner);`) tasks that don't finish operation, because the actual test if finished earlier and the object get's disposed, I guess purging the background thread execution.

Is there a way I can set my class to not be getting disposed after the test stuff is ran, to ensure that background tasks are finished?

Comment: Possible design issues aside, you can expose a Wait() method in your class and internally Join() on your background threads.

Comment: Do you actually mean “disposed” or do you mean “garbage collected”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can set my class to not be getting disposed after the
>   test stuff is ran, to ensure that background tasks are finished?

You may have some design issues here. `Dispose` should normally be the last thing called in your unit test (unless you are specifically testing `Dispose`). At this point the test should have already reported a failure or is about to pass. By calling `Dispose` you, the developer, are saying that there is no longer any need to use the class. If you no longer need to use the class then why does it matter that the background tasks are terminated early. Do you understand what I am getting at?

If there is a specific operation on your class that is dependent on those background tasks completing then the method used to invoke that operation should internally wait for those tasks to complete before proceeding. This would cause that method to block which in turn should cause your test code to block as well. If the method being tested is asynchronous then your class should expose a mechanism for waiting until the operation is complete.

Comment: Last sentence says what I need. What kind of a mechanism can it be? Like `myCallInstance.WaitToBackgroundThreadToFinish()` synchronous method being called before disposing an object under test? What would be inside? How do I lock on waiting for other background threads from inside the class?

Comment: I think you may have missed my point. If you need a `WaitToBackgroundThreadToFinish` method to be called before `Dispose` to make your class work correctly then your design may have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just heard about PNUnit so you may check if it has something you can use otherwise you may simply enumerate each background thread and perform a Thread.Join on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a [TearDown](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=teardown&r=2.6) method for your test that delays the test from completing until the background work is handled.